# Record is Deleted Error in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a record in a table which is causing me to get the "Record is Deleted" error. I identified the record which is causing this error, but when I manually delete that line, it comes right back. Any tips on how to  delete this corrupted line permanently from the table?

Comment: Is the operation committed after you perform the manual delete?  Even Access has the concept of commit...  While it has been years since I used Access, and I am uncertain, this sounds like a feasible root cause.

Comment: If i go back into the table after deleting the entry, it comes back. I have form with a button to open up the table but when I click on it i get the "record is deleted error". I am no access guru, but I am pretty sure that one line is the culprit here. Just cant seem to keep that line deleted permanently.

Comment: Have you run Compact & Repair? Then see if the record is still there and if so try delete. Try copying the table or copy/paste records to a new table.

Comment: I couldn't open the table, so I copied and created a new one. I deleted the old table, and the new one opens up fine but still has the error. Tried running Compact & repair..still no luck

Comment: Do you have Data Macros defined on the table?  Precisely what do you mean by "open the table"?  That might sound like a dumb question, but you mention a form and a button.  What if you skip the form and go right to the default datasheet view that comes up when you double click in the Navigation Pane?  Do you still get the strange behavior?

Comment: The tb_PV_Approval is a linked table from another DB. There is one record that shows up with #Deleted under each column of data. I can manualy delete that record, but when i open up the table again, its back. I used the Linked Table manager to go to the other DB where the table is stored and it has the same issue. I can delete the record but it keeps coming back.

Comment: I ended up Copying and creating a new table in the other DB and pasting structure only (no data) and it worked. Deleted the tbl_PV_Approval and renamed the new copied table to the same name and no more errors. Thanks everyone for your help.